# Track the generation of an html snippet in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

On one website, there is an html snippet dynamically generated by some javascript function in some javascript code,

for example, `<div class="so"></div>` is dynamically generated and inserted by javascript funciton `insertso()` in `so.js`.

However, the javascript code is obfuscated, and there are lots of other javascript files loaded by this site.

Is it possible to use Chrome or other tools to find out which function in which javascript file generate this html snippet?

Comment: In which manner is the text within the files obfuscated?